# accessing SessionState in Global.Application_Error

Tags: asp.net, session-state, global-asax

In the Application_Error method in Global.asax I am trying to retrieve a value from session state.

I am able to access session state as long as I throw the exception. EG:

```
thow new Exception("Test exception");
```

However if it is an unhandled exception, i get the following error when trying to access session state: "Session state is not available in this context.".

Why the differences in behavior, is there a work around?

Thanks.

Comment: That is weird behaviour. I use a similar setup to record form and session info on exceptions for notification purposes with no issue. I will verify this in the morning at work.  :)

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow what you're trying to do. If you manually throw an exception everything works? Could you give a more complete code sample of what works and what doesnt?

Answer (score 2):

I hate ASP.NET sometimes...

So generating an error using:

```
Response.Redirect("thispagedoesnotexist.aspx", false);
```

The above line will redirect to Application_Error with session state not available

However

```
throw new Exception("test");
```

The above line will redirect to Application_Error with session state AVAILABLE

So instead of doing this all in Application_Error, in one spot, I will have to use try/catches through out my code to catch errors. Then gather data from session, log and email error details, then finally redirect to friendly error page. Lots of extra code..

Conclusion: Application_Error is worthless.

Comment: 1. The case you mentioned is fairly intuitive if you know the page life cycle. In the second case, you throw an exception more towards the bottom of the cycle, where the request state is populated, where as in the first case the request would not get a chance to do so.
2. For your error handling cases, use ELMAH. It does all the collecting / emailing for you. No extra code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access the session through HttpContext.Current.Session. I believe the difference in behavior is that in the unhanded exception handler, the request has gone into "Failsafe" mode and the page lifecycle (including loading and disposing the session) has finished.

Check out this page on the [lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) for more info