# I've had an issue on session lost while the config file is like the following:

Tags: c#, session

I've had an issue on session lost while the config file is like the following:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424"
              cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="30"/>
```

and my application_error handler was like this:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lastExp = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
    if (lastExp != null )
    {
        var expHelper = new ExceptionHelper();

        Session["ErrorMessage"] = lastExp ;

        if (exp != null)
        {                   
            Server.ClearError();
            this.Response.Redirect(ErrorPage.VirtualPath, true);                   
        }              
    }          
}
```

and on my errorPage I couldn't access the session key so the ErrorPage had blank message to show; and I got the `threw an exception of type System.Web.HttpException` exception on that specific sessionKey.

Comment: I don't really see a question in here, but I guess the answer is in [accessing SessionState in Global.Application\_Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300093/accessing-sessionstate-in-global-application-error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to over come this issue  with StateServer mode of SessionState, you should handle every error on pages on Page_Error; you can create a base class which inherites from system.web.page and  get the error then clean up the server errors and let the request of that page to commit changes in session for later use.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/06/26/a-case-of-lost-session-variables-when-using-out-of-process-session-state.aspx

for more info about StateServer mode check this link out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178586.aspx